# Почему переменную R::store($user_change); не передаются значения при попытке обновить их в бд?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, input, redbeanphp

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не получается обновить в бд данные?

Пример инпута и пример запроса

```
<label class="form-label" for="account-username">Логин</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="account-username" 
name="new_login" placeholder="<?php echo $logged_user_login; ?>" value=" 
<?php echo @$data['new_login'];?>"/>


 <?php 
 require 'db.php';
 session_start(); 


 $data = $_POST;
 if( isset($data['do_data']) ) {
 $errors = array();
 $showError = True;

 if ( $data['user_name'] == "" ) {
    $errors[] = 'Введите имя и фамилию';
 }

 if ( $data['user_phone'] == "" ) {
    $errors[] = 'Введите телефон';
 }

 if ( $data['user_country'] == "" ) {
    $errors[] = 'Введите название компании';
 }

 if( R::count('users', "login = ?", array($data['new_login'])) > 0)  {
  $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином существует';

 }


 if( empty($errors)) {
    //$user_ids = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
    $user_change = R::findOne('users', "id = ?", array($_SESSION['logged_user']->id));
    //$user_change = R::exec("UPDATE `users` WHERE `id` = ?", ["$ids"]);
    //$user_change = R::load('user', $_SESSION['logged_user']->id);
    $user_change->login = $data['new_login'];
    $user_change->name = $data['user_name'];
    $user_change->phone = $data['user_phone'];
    $user_change->country = $data['user_country'];
    R::store($user_change);
    
    exit;
   }
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Так вы же пример запроса не привели. Это что-то вроде запроса к запросу. Покажите что внутри `R::store`? Если не передаются `$user_change` покажите что возвращаете в `R::findOne`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы ничего не находите в findOne и дальше ничего не обновляете. Это происходит, вероятно, потому, что вы стартуете сессию после начала вывода. В документации к [session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php) сказано:

> Для использования сессий на основе cookie, функция session_start() должна быть вызвана перед выводом чего бы то ни было в браузер.

Опытные программисты никогда не сталкиваются с такими проблемами, потому что они разрабатывают в окружении, которое не подавляет никакие ошибки. То есть у них есть локальная копия сайта, для которой [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) установлен в `E_ALL` и [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) = 1.

Вы можете временно включить отображение ошибок для своего кусочка кода через функцию [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php) и отображение ошибок через [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php);

Опытные разработчики так же всегда кодируют обработку ошибок и особых случаев. Если метод может вернуть строку из базы данных или null, то для варианта с null обязательно надо написать код.

```
$logged_user = $_SESSION['logged_user']?? null;
if ($logged_user === null) {
    throw new \Exception('Пользователь не залогинен.');
}

$user_change = R::findOne('users', 'id = ?', [$logged_user->id]);
if ($user_change === null) {
    throw new \Exception(sprintf('Не найден пользователь %d', $logged_user->id));
}
```